# WPF Conflicting animations

Tags: wpf, animation

I have two animations that controls the color of the border of a TextBox. One animation changes the color from the default yellow to blue, and one animation changes the color back to the default. These animations are started with triggers on IsFocused. This works fine.

Now I want the same animations to be trigged by IsMouseOver as well. My desired behavior is that the border of the TextBox should be blue if it has focus or if the mouse hovers over it, otherwise it should be yellow. And there should be an animated transition between the states.

As mentioned, to change color with an animation when the TextBox gets or loses focus is not a problem. Neither is there a problem changing the color when the mouse moves over the TextBox. The problem is having BOTH. Then there is a conflict...

How can I have both these animations?

Here's some code with both animations, but that does NOT work as I want it to due to the conflict. What happens is that if I hover over the TextBox once the animation will never run on IsFocused again...

```
<TextBox Width="200" Height="140" BorderBrush="Yellow" BorderThickness="4">
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Style.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="RecievedFocusOrMouseOverAnimation">
                        <ColorAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush.(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                            To="Blue" 
                            Duration="0:0:0.2" />
                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="LostFocusOrMouseOutAnimation">
                        <ColorAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush.(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                            To="Yellow" 
                            Duration="0:0:0.2" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </Style.Resources>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Name="IsFocusedTrueBeginStoryBoard" Storyboard="{StaticResource RecievedFocusOrMouseOverAnimation}" />
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Name="IsFocusedFalseBeginStoryBoard" Storyboard="{StaticResource LostFocusOrMouseOutAnimation}" />
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Name="IsMouseOverTrueBeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource RecievedFocusOrMouseOverAnimation}" />
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Name="IsMouseOverFalseBeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource LostFocusOrMouseOutAnimation}" />
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you try to use a MultiDataTrigger with an OR condition like described [here](http://www.charlierobbins.com/articles/2009/03/16/wpf-tips-how-to-use-a-multitrigger-with-an-or-condition/). Your code should be something like this:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Value="True">
            <Condition.Binding>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BooleanOr}">
                    <Binding Path="IsMouseOver" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource self}" />
                    <Binding Path="IsFocused" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource self}" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </Condition.Binding>
        </Condition>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
         <BeginStoryboard Name="IsFocusedTrueBeginStoryBoard" Storyboard="{StaticResource RecievedFocusOrMouseOverAnimation}" />
    </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
    <MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Name="IsFocusedFalseBeginStoryBoard" Storyboard="{StaticResource LostFocusOrMouseOutAnimation}" />
    </MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

`BooleanOr` is a `IMultiValueConverter` that computes an OR between all its arguments (you can find it in the code attached to the article in the link).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to Stop the potential running Storyboards before you begin a new one. Try this

```
<Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
    <Trigger.EnterActions>
        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="IsMouseOverTrueBeginStoryboard"/>
        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="IsMouseOverFalseBeginStoryboard"/>
        <BeginStoryboard Name="IsFocusedTrueBeginStoryBoard" Storyboard="{StaticResource RecievedFocusOrMouseOverAnimation}" />
    </Trigger.EnterActions>
    <Trigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Name="IsFocusedFalseBeginStoryBoard" Storyboard="{StaticResource LostFocusOrMouseOutAnimation}" />
    </Trigger.ExitActions>
</Trigger>
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Trigger.EnterActions>
        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="IsFocusedTrueBeginStoryBoard"/>
        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="IsFocusedFalseBeginStoryBoard"/>
        <BeginStoryboard Name="IsMouseOverTrueBeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource RecievedFocusOrMouseOverAnimation}" />
    </Trigger.EnterActions>
    <Trigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Name="IsMouseOverFalseBeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource LostFocusOrMouseOutAnimation}" />
    </Trigger.ExitActions>
</Trigger>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm afraid the solution has flaws. For example try this: Hold the mouse pointer over the TextBox - Border turns blue. Move focus to the TextBox - Border quickly turns yellow then changes to blue (the animation is run again). Move mouse pointer out from the TextBox - Border turns yellow, even though the TextBox still has focus... Thanks anyway though, since I learned about the StopStoryBoard. :)

Comment: @haagel: You're right. Nothing stops the `IsMouseOverFalseBeginStoryboard` from occuring which turns the `Border` yellow and nothing changes it back to blue since this IsFocused Storyboard has already run its blue animation :)